# Calculate value from subgrid in CRM

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, subgrid

I need to make a plugin to recalculate all the Opportunity products from my subgrid on opportunity form.

The new logic: I added 2 new custom fields on products : ONE TIME FEE & RECURRING FEE.
These will be visible on the subgrid Products on the Opportunity form.

I need to know how to start to retrieve the values from the column.
I am familiar with Jscript and .Net (csharp) but this will be my first plugin for CRM, as I don't know how this works.

thanks

Comment: My first question would be what will trigger the "recalculate"?

Comment: adding or removing, the products from the subgrid